# sh script containing perl element does not produce same output via crontab as manual execution

Tags: shell-script, files, cron, perl

I tried posting this on Stackexchange but I think I may have more chance of a correct answer here as its very linux specific. 
I have an sh script which updates data in a csv, then runs a perl script ($match) from within the sh script that matches data between two csv files and populates the file $matches with the matching results. I'm only going to show a snippet from the end of the script because only this bit is relevant to the question:

```
#!/bin/sh
export PATH="/opt/bin:/opt/sbin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/syno/sbin:/usr/syno/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin"

match=/home/perl_experiments/newitems/match.pl       
matches=/home/perl_experiments/newitems/matches.txt


/usr/bin/perl $match > $matches

if [[ -s $matches ]] ; then
    date >> $log
    echo "matches has data." >> $log
    $sendmail
else
    date >> $log                  
    echo "matches is empty." >> $log
    exit                              
fi
```

EDIT: Here is the $match script

```
#!/usr/bin/perl                                                                                                                                                                              

my @csv2 = ();                                                                                                                                                                               
open CSV2, "<csv2" or die;                                                                                                                                                                   
@csv2=<CSV2>;                                                                                                                                                                                
close CSV2;                                                                                                                                                                                  

my %csv2hash = ();                                                                                                                                                                           
for (@csv2) {                                                                                                                                                                                
  chomp;                                                                                                                                                                                     
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title                                                                                                                                
  $csv2hash{$_} = $title;                                                                                                                                                                    
}                                                                                                                                                                                            

open CSV1, "<csv1" or die;                                                                                                                                                                   
while (<CSV1>) {                                                                                                                                                                             
  chomp;                                                                                                                                                                                     
  my ($title) = $_ =~ /^.+?,\s*([^,]+?),/; #/ match the title                                                                                                                                
    my %words;                                                                                                                                                                               
    $words{$_}++ for split /\s+/, $title;    #/ get words                                                                                                                                    
    ## Collect unique words                                                                                                                                                                  
    my @titlewords = keys(%words);                                                                                                                                                           
  my @new;                          #add exception words which shouldn't be matched                                                                                                          
  foreach my $t (@titlewords){                                                                                                                                                               
        push(@new, $t) if $t !~ /^(and|the|to|uk)$/i;                                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                                                                          
  @titlewords = @new;                                                                                                                                                                        
  my $desired = 5;                                                                                                                                                                           
  my $matched = 0;                                                                                                                                                                           
  foreach my $csv2 (keys %csv2hash) {                                                                                                                                                        
    my $count = 0;                                                                                                                                                                           
    my $value = $csv2hash{$csv2};                                                                                                                                                            
    foreach my $word (@titlewords) {                                                                                                                                                         
            my @matches   = ( $value=~/\b$word\b/ig );                                                                                                                                       
            my $numIncsv2 = scalar(@matches);                                                                                                                                                
            @matches      = ( $title=~/\b$word\b/ig );                                                                                                                                       
            my $numIncsv1 = scalar(@matches);                                                                                                                                                
            ++$count if $value =~ /\b$word\b/i;                                                                                                                                              
            if ($count >= $desired || ($numIncsv1 >= $desired && $numIncsv2 >= $desired)) {                                                                                                  
                $count = $desired+1;                                                                                                                                                         
                last;                                                                                                                                                                        
            }                                                                                                                                                                                
    }                                                                                                                                                                                        
    if ($count >= $desired) {                                                                                                                                                                
      print "$csv2\n";                                                                                                                                                                       
      ++$matched;                                                                                                                                                                            
    }                                                                                                                                                                                        
  }                                                                                                                                                                                          
  print "$_\n\n" if $matched;                                                                                                                                                                
}                                                                                                                                                                                            
close CSV1;                                                                                                                                                                                  
~
```

Now, i've deliberately left some data in the 2 csv's that matches to test the script. When I run the script manually it works as expected and I get the message "matches has data" in the $log file. However, when its run from crontab (as root, just like when I run it manualy) it doesn't produces any data in $matches- and the $log files entry states "matches is empty."

Here is my crontab entry, which definitely runs the script, it just doesn't produce the expected output:

```
*/10    09-21   *       *       1,2,3,4,5       root    /home/perl_experiments/newitems/newitems.sh
```

So my question is, why is this happening, and what can I amend to ensure crontab executions are the same as my manual executions? Is it something to do with crontab having issues with running a perl script inside an sh script?

As I say when run manually it does exactly what I expect it to, but when run my crontab, no matches are produced. Suggestions welcome.

Comment: you're using `[[` as a test operator, but that's bash-specific, and your she-bang line explicitly says `/bin/sh`

Comment: Really? In that case why does it work when I manually execute the script?

Comment: do you have bash as your interactive shell?

Comment: not sure, when I type "which bash" nothing comes up

Comment: Ahh I see evidence of a Synology NAS; if you enter `/bin/sh` and then type `[[ -d / ]] && echo yes`, does it work or give an error? Not sure if their /bin/sh supports [[

Comment: yes it says /bin/sh: can't open '[['

Comment: but i've just installed bash and tried /opt/bin/bash [[ -d / ]] && echo yes and that also produces an error "/usr/bin/[[: /usr/bin/[[: cannot execute binary file"

Comment: I'll be using bash on my NAS from now on though, I din't realise it would be so easy to install on my NAS so thanks for the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your perl script has

```
open CSV2, "<csv2" or die;
...
open CSV1, "<csv1" or die;
```

Where are those files located? cron's current directory is the home directory of the user. If the files are in the "newitems" directory, you have to `cd` there first.

Make sure you're not making any other assumptions about the environment in your programs.

I find this is a handy command to enable in your crontab one time:

```
#* * * * * { date; pwd; echo "env:"; env; echo "set:"; set; } > ~/cron.env
```

---

An excellent point by @Otheus:

```
if ! /usr/bin/perl "$match" > "$matches"; then
    status=$?
    echo "$match script returned unsuccessfully"
    exit $status
fi
```

Comment: ok, let me give that a go, i'll be back like Arnie

Comment: @nmh i was going to raise same issue, with note that you never check output status of perl run in the shell script. You should test $? or wrap yhe execution in `if` clause.